# Xamarin.Forms localization on the fly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to download and use language files (`.resx`) on the fly, so I do not have to do a new release, when a new language become available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to serialize your translations in a json format so that you just have to update this file.

You create a class that contains your translation.

```
public class LanguagePack
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = ="LPT")]
    public string LoginPageTitle{get;set;}

    public static LanguagePack Current {get; set;}
}
```

In your xaml, you can do this

```
<Label Text="{x:static LanguagePack.Current.LoginPageTitle}"/>
```

When you get your translation from your server, you can do this (maybe store it somewhere first)

```
LanguagePack.Current = JsonConvert.Deserialize(yourJsonFile);
```

Comment: Can I write to the file on-the-fly? 
And can I clear the values from the other language on-the-fly too?

Comment: You just map an object to your translation file. Let me edit my answer.